# How do I find out a blocks ID?

Tags: blocks

```
$block = module_invoke('menu_block', 'block', 'view', 26); 
print $block['content'];
```

I am trying to use this code to print out a block, but I do not know how to get the ID for the last parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to look for the [hook_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6) implementation done from the module for which you are invoking `module_invoke()`. The last argument in the function call you reported is the `$delta` parameter that is used from Drupal to identify the block within the module.

For example, looking at the code of [forum_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--forum--forum.module/function/forum_block/6), the part of the code that implement the "list" operation, 0 is the delta parameter for the "Active forum topics" block, and 1 is the delta parameter for "New forum topics" block.

The code you wrote in your question is invoking the implementation of `hook_block` made from a module whose short name is menu_block (which means the function implementing the hook is `menu_block_block()`). If you meant to invoke the implementation of `hook_block()` made from menu.module, then the code should be the following one:

```
$block = module_invoke('menu', 'block', 'view', 26); 
print $block['content'];
```

The function implementing `hook_block()` is [menu_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--menu--menu.module/function/menu_block/6). The values used as `$delta` from that function are the values of the "menu_name" field used in the "menu_custom" table.

Answer (score 1):

[How to insert a block into a tpl or into content programmatically with Drupal](http://www.pixelclever.com/how-insert-a-block-a-tpl-or-content-programmatically-with-drupal)

See part "Where do I get that information for the block I am trying to call?" at bottom...

Since it was removed from site, I am putting text from cached history of site:

---

Where do I get that information for the block I am trying to call?

The easiest way is to go to the blocks page and to hover over the “configure” link. Without clicking on the link look in the bottom left hand corner of your browser (at least with Firefox) there you should see the URL that you would be taken to upon clicking. The important information that you need is in the last two elements of the URL. So if the URL of the link is admin/build/block/configure/jquerymenu/0 then the module that created that block is the jquerymenu block and the $delta (or block number) is 0.

So to review, the example code calls module_invoke with the following arguments: 'jquerymenu', 'block', 'view', 0 . What this does is call the jquermenu module, it calls its hook_block, tells it that it wants the information that is returned under $op = ‘view’ and that it wants only the information from the block with the $delta of 0.

Now that you have the $block (which is an array) you need to get the ‘content’ element from it by calling $block[‘content’]. You could also call the title by using $block[‘title’].

I hope that makes this code snippet make sense for you. You can find more information regarding module_invoke at http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_invoke.

Comment: Link is 404. Is it possible to update the link